# Fetch in fetch inside a loop JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, fetch-api

The question is, how can I get rid of calling second fetch 300 times? Or is there another way to do that, what I`m doing?
Additionally how to do ordered(don`t wanna sort) calls of first api, because they`re coming from api in chaotic asynchronous way?

```
for(let i=1;i<=300; i++) {
  fetch(`example.api/incomes/${i}`)   // should be returned 300 times
    .then(response => {
      if(response.ok) return response.json();
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    })
    .then(function handleData(data) {
        return fetch('example.api')   // should be returned 1 time
        .then(response => {
            if(response.ok) return response.json();
            throw new Error(response.statusText);
          })
    })
    .catch(function handleError(error) {
        console.log("Error" +error);            
    }); 
};
```

Comment: So you want to call the first `fetch` 300 times, then after all fetches are finished, call the second one?

Comment: If you have control over the API, I would suggest you to implement some sort of batching mechanism. 300 API calls will just slow down whatever you're doing and overload your API server.

Comment: Yup, and they should have access to retrieve data of each other. First fetch is a 300 objects that are should be bonded corresponding to ID of an items in array of second fetch.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb it`s like same API, but each item lays down under different api adress. So i`m using {i} parameter to have access to it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can solve it using Promise all.

```
let promises = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {
  promises.push(fetch(`example.api/incomes/${i}`));
}
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(function handleData(data) {
    return fetch("example.api") // should be returned 1 time
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) return response.json();
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
      });
  })
  .catch(function handleError(error) {
    console.log("Error" + error);
  });
```

Comment: I want to grab my GH repos https://api.github.com/users/tik9/repos with `Promise` and then do a fetch to another api to change the ISO Date to another date format. But `Promise` does not work, I get `TypeError: response.json is not a function` with `promises =[];promises.push(fetch(github));Promise.all(promises).then((response) => response.json())`

Comment: `Promise.all` will return array of response, you need to loop. `Promise.all(promises).then((responses) => responses.map(r => .json()))`

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are perfectly valid, but a bit outdated. Here is a new way of doing it with async/await:

```js
async function repeat(uri, amount) {
    const result = []
    for (let i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
        const response = await fetch(`${uri}/${i}`) // waits for the response
        const data = await response.json()
        result.push(...data)
    }

    return data
}

repeat('example.api/incomes', 300)
    .then(handleData) // defined elsewhere or anonymous
    .catch(handleError) // defined elsewhere or anonymous
}
```

If you don't know about this, async/await is basically a clearer way to write promises.

> The `async function` declaration creates a binding of a new async function to a given name. The `await` keyword is permitted within the function body, enabling asynchronous, promise-based behavior to be written in a cleaner style and avoiding the need to explicitly configure promise chains.

([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function))

Answer (score 0):

Store all of your requests in an array. Then use `Promise.all()` the wait for all of those requests to finish. Then when all of the requests are finished, use another `Promise.all()` with a `map()` inside of it to return the the JSON of each request and wait for all of those to finish.

Now your `data` argument will have an array of objects available in the next `then` callback.

```
function fetch300Times() {
  let responses = [];
  for(let i = 1; i <= 300; i++) {.
    let response = fetch(`example.api/incomes/${i}`);
    responses.push(response);
  } 
  return Promise.all(responses);
}

const awaitJson = (response) => Promise.all(responses.map(response => {
  if(response.ok) return response.json();
  throw new Error(response.statusText);
}));

fetch300Times()
  .then(awaitJson)
  .then(data => {
    fetch('example.api')   // should be returned 1 time
      .then(response => {
        if(response.ok) return response.json();
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
      });
  }).catch(function handleError(error) {
    console.log("Error" +error);            
  });
```