# For loop with fetch returning empty array

Tags: javascript, express, promise, fetch

I'm writing a server route that makes api calls.

I need to make two different fetch requests cause I need more info that's coming in the first fetch.

The problem is that I'm declaring a variable out of the promise scope and for some reason, my `res.send` is not awaiting until the array gets full.

I need to iterate until result 9 (I can't use theDogApi's predefined filters to show nine results!)

```
if (req.query.name) {
    var myRes = [];
    fetch(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds/search?name=${req.query.name}&apikey=${key}`)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then( data => {

            for (let i = 0; i < 8 && i < data.length; i++) {
                fetch(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/${data[i].reference_image_id
                    }`)
                    .then(r => r.json())
                    .then(datos => {

                        myRes.push({ ...data[i], ...datos });
                    })
            }
        })
        .then(res.send(myRes))
}
```

I'll appreciate the help!

Comment: Use PromiseAll. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60710890/15237039)

Comment: Good time to use an `async function` with `await`, or some other Promise structure.

Comment: You also don't have a return statement in your second `.then()` and your third `.then()` will produce a syntax error.

Comment: @WeiYan that's helpfull but i don't really know how to implement it on my code..

Comment: Reopening because this question is not really about returning a value from the function.  it's more about managing loops of asynchronous operations and other asynchronous coding mistakes.

Comment: Many things wrong here, Here's one part that is wrong: `.then(res.send(myRes))` is never correct.,  Change to `.then(() => { res.send(myRes);})`.  You have to pass a function reference to `.then()` so it can be called LATER when the promise actually resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an `async function` unsing `await`:

```js
async function fun(queryName, key){
  const a = [], p, j = [];
  let firstWait = await fetch(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds/search?name=${req.query.name}&apikey=${key}`);
  let firstJson = await firstWait.json(); // must be an Array
  for(let i=0,n=8,j,l=firstJson.length; i<n && i<l; i++){
    a.push(fetch('https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/'+firstJson[i].reference_image_id));
  }
  p = await Promise.all(a);
  for(let v of p){
    j.push(v.json());
  }
  return Promise.all(j);
}
// assumes req, req.query, req.query.name, and key are already defined
fun(req.query.name, key).then(a=>{
  // a is your JSON Array
});
```

Comment: that `for` loop is so hard on the eyes. have you seen `for..of`, or `Array.prototype.map`?

Comment: @Thankyou, of course I know about those loops. My second loop is a `for..of` loop. The `for` loop is very simple to read. `;` separates `initial_vars; condition; increment_vars`.  `,` separates `initial_vars`, and could separate `increment_vars`, as well. OP needed the loop to be less that `8`. Yeah, I could have got rid of `, j = []` up top, and done like `const j = p.map(o=>o.json());` instead of the `for..of` loop, but I doubt it would increase performance, and that's easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to turn your array of `fetch` calls into an aggregate promise that resolves to an array of responses when all have arrived. If any fail, the whole thing fails (use `Promise.allSettled` if you don't want all-or-nothing semantics). Don't forget to catch the error.

Although the code doesn't show it, be sure to check `response.ok` to make sure the request actually succeeded before calling `.json()`. Throwing an error if `!repsonse.ok` and handling it in the `.catch` block is a typical strategy. Writing a wrapper on `fetch` is not a bad idea to avoid verbosity.

Lastly, note that [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) replaces the `for` loop. For arrays with fewer than 8 elements, it'll slice as many as are available without issue.

```js
// mock everything
const fetch = (() => {
  const responses = [
    {
      json: async () => 
        [...Array(10)].map((e, i) => ({reference_image_id: i}))
    },
    ...Array(10)
      .fill()
      .map((_, i) => ({json: async () => i})),
  ];
  return async () => responses.shift();
})();
const req = {query: {name: "doberman"}};
const key = "foobar";
const res = {send: response => console.log(`sent ${response}`)};
// end mocks

fetch(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds/search?name=${req.query.name}&apikey=${key}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => 
    Promise.all(data.slice(0, 8).map(e =>
      fetch(`https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/${e.reference_image_id}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
    ))
  )
  .then(results => res.send(results))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

**JSON**

Here's my hot take: Stop using low-level functions like `fetch` every time you want to get JSON. This tangles up fetching logic every time we want to get a bit of JSON. Write `getJSON` once and use it wherever you need JSON -

```js
const getJSON = s =>
  fetch(s).then(r => r.json())

const data =
  await getJSON("https://path/to/some/data.json")

// ...
```

---

**URL and URLSearchParams**

Another hot take: Stop writing all of your URLs by hand. This tangles URL writing/rewriting with all of your api access logic. We can setup a `DogApi` endpoint once, with a base url and an `apikey` -

```js
const DogApi =
  withApi("https://api.thedogapi.com/v1", {apikey: "0xdeadbeef"})
```

And now whenever we need to touch that endpoint, the base url and default params can be inserted for us -

```
const breed = 
  // https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/breeds/search?apikey=0xdeadbeef&name=chihuahua
  await getJSON(DogApi("/breeds/search", {name}))
    

// ...
```

`withApi` has a simple implementation -

```js
const withApi = (base, defaults) => (pathname, params) =>
{ const u = new URL(url) // <- if you don't know it, learn URL
  u.pathname = pathname 
  setParams(u, defaults)
  setParams(u, params)
  return u.toString()
}

function setParams (url, params = {})
{ for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(params))
    url.searchParams.set(k, v)  // <- if you don't know it, learn URLSearchParams
  return url
}
```

---

**fruits of your labor**

Now it's dead simple to write functions like `imagesForBreed`, and any other functions that touch JSON or your DogApi -

```js
async function imagesForBreed (name = "")
{ if (name == "")
    return []

  const breed = 
    await getJSON(DogApi("/breeds/search", {name}))

  const images =
    data.map(v => getJSON(DogAPI(`/images/${v.reference_image_id}`))
  
  return Promise.all(images)
}
```

And your entire Express handler is reduced to a single line, with no need to touch `.then` or other laborious API configuration -

```js
async function fooHandler (req, res)
{ 
   res.send(imagesForBreed(req.query.name))
}
```