# .push() does not work under throw, using async await method to fetch data in a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, async-await, fetch, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data one by one in order using async await and push the response.json to a array. However, the code I use below does not display the result in `console.log(b);`. Any one know what's the issue?

Thank you in advance!

```
async function fetch_data(){

    let b = [];
    
    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

        let response = await fetch('https://SOME_URL/' + i, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {"Key": "123456"}})


        if (!response.ok) {
        var error_detail = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
        throw new Error(error_detail);
        }

        var data = await response.json();

        // await b.push(data);
        b.push(data);
    }

    // await Promise.all(b).then(function (b) {
    //         console.log(b)})

    console.log(b);
    return b;

}
```

When I run the script, it does not return anything in the console

```
fetch_data().catch(error => {
  error.error_detail;
});
```

UPDATE: seems solved using my answer below. not sure why though.

The issue in which `console.log(b);` not displaying the output is because for example `'https://SOME_URL/' + i`  as `i` increases, IF when `i = 5` and it returns error, then the `console.log(b);` will not return anything. If I set the `i < 5`, then `console.log(b);` will return the output b. So which means if any fetch in the loop returns error within the limit of `i`, then the push will not work (b will be empty) and hence `console.log(b);` will not return anything.

Anyone have idea how to solve this?

Comment: Rename the function to something else (_fetch for example)

Comment: I don't think you need to await `b.push(data)`.  It's just an array push.

Comment: I modified it, and it is still not returning anything.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60710890/1980846

Comment: I will take a look at it and will remove if it's working! Thanks!

Comment: Your code works fine for me as it is. I used `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated several places
One of the issues would be the function name: "fetch" as same as the default fetch function name.

```js
const fetchData = async(symbol) => {
  try {
    let promiseGroup = [];

    const subFetch = async(i) => {
      const BASE_URL = `https://reqres.in/api/products`
      return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/${i}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Key": "123456"
        }
      }).then(res => res.json())
    }

    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      promiseGroup.push(i);
    }   
    const results = await Promise.all(promiseGroup.map(subFetch))
    console.log(results)
    return result;

  } catch (error) {
    const error_detail = `An error has occured: ${error}`;
    throw new Error(error_detail);
  }
}
console.log(fetchData())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename your function. The error you get is `Maximum call stack size exceeded` since when you call `fetch` inside the loop you actually call the outer function, and not the function you want.

Comment: Hi Jesper, I did rename my function and it is still not returning anything.

Comment: The inner fetch never calls the outer loop nor the fetch_data function, so in this instance renaming will not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version (at least its working for me):
Basically I just removed the header and indented it a bit, so your example should work as well. Maybe you have some issue on the backend ?

```js
async function fetch_data() {
  let b = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + i, {
      method: "GET",
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      var error_detail = `An error has occured: ${response.status}`;
      throw new Error(error_detail);
    }

    var data = await response.json();
    // await b.push(data);
    b.push(data);
  }

  console.log(b);
  return b;
}

fetch_data()
  .then(data => console.log(data.length))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: That's really weird. I have to add headers and the fetch part with header is definitely working because it does output json data being pushed to the array b in every iteration in console when I put ```console.log(b)``` right after ```b.push(data)```

Comment: Hi all, I think I know the issue. It because for example ```https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + i ``` as i increases, if when i = 5 and it returns error, then the  ```console.log(b);``` will not return anything.  If I set the i < 5, then  ```console.log(b);``` will return the b. So which means if any fetch returns error within the limit of i, then ```console.log(b);```  will not return anything. How to solve this? @ggorelen @Goran.it

Answer (score 0):

Changing `throw new Error(error_detail);` to `break` seems solved the issue and able to display the result.